# Align input element with his label

Tags: html, css

I would like to align the border of an input with the bottom of his label.

I've tried to change their height but the rendering was not always the same. Here is what I get for now:
[This is a link to the picture of what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHNxc.png)

*(I have removed the height attribute, it wasn't effective)*

```css
#options_body_search {
    width: 100%;
    height: 3vh;
    margin: 1vh 0 0.8vh 0;
}

#options_body_search .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 70%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#options_body_search label {
    display: block;
    width: 22.5%;
    height: 55%;
    padding: 0.5vh;
    font-size: 0.7vw;
    font-weight: bolder;
    background: #1C57A5;
    color: #FDFFFC;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}

#options_body_search input {
    display: block;
    font-size: 0.7vw;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 2px #1C57A5 solid;
}

#options_body_search input::placeholder {
    font-size: 0.7vw;
}
```

```html
<div id="options_body_search">
    <div class="container">
        <label for="global_search">Recherche:</label>
        <input id="global_search" type="text" placeholder="Rechercher dans toutes les colonnes" size="35">
    </div>
</div>
```

*(The "size" attribute is added by JQuery)*

It would be perfect if the border-bottom of the input was aligned with the bottom of the label.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your link, though it does go to Imgur, does not link to the image you suggest.

Comment: When i am running your code I am getting it perfectly aligned.

Comment: @DavidThomas I can't use image, I need 10 reputation.

Comment: @MonikaMangal It depends on many factors. They were lined up at first too.

Comment: Well, yes, but the Imgur link doesn't - on mobile at least - link to an image relevant to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
#options_body_search {
    width: 100%;
    height: 3vh;
    margin: 1vh 0 0.8vh 0;
}

#options_body_search .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 70%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    align-items: flex-end;
}

#options_body_search label {
    display: block;
    width: 22.5%;
    height: 55%;
    padding: 0.5vh;
    font-size: 0.7vw;
    font-weight: bolder;
    background: #1C57A5;
    color: #FDFFFC;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}

#options_body_search input {
    display: block;
    font-size: 0.7vw;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 2px #1C57A5 solid;
}

#options_body_search input::placeholder {
    font-size: 0.7vw;
}
```

```html
<div id="options_body_search">
    <div class="container">
        <label for="global_search">Recherche:</label>
        <input id="global_search" type="text" placeholder="Rechercher dans toutes les colonnes" size="35">
    </div>
</div>
```

Give align-items:flex-end to the container class

Comment: That was pretty simple. Thanks, that works exactly like I wanted

Answer (score 0):

try following.

```css
#options_body_search {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 1vh 0 0.8vh 0;
}

#options_body_search .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 70%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#options_body_search label {
    display: block;
    width: 22.5%;
    padding: 0.5vh;
    font-weight: bolder;
    background: #1C57A5;
    color: #FDFFFC;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}

#options_body_search input {
    display: block;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 2px #1C57A5 solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="options_body_search">
    <div class="container">
        <label for="global_search">Recherche:</label>
        <input id="global_search" type="text" placeholder="Rechercher dans toutes les colonnes" size="35">
    </div>
</div>
```